# Import Jars from a different folder into the existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have common libraries placed in a Common libraries folder in order to access all the jars from that folder.

So I have multiple projects and I want to import the common libraries folder directly into my project in eclipse. I don't know how to add the folder in Java build path.

In Eclipse:
Project --> Java build Path --> libraries

I see Add jars/Add External Jars/Add Projects/Add class Folder options in libraries, but I don't know how can I add the jars into the libraries folder directly as a folder that contains all jars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - Adding a Jar File to a existing Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395095/eclipse-adding-a-jar-file-to-a-existing-project)

Comment: @pringi I am not looking to add a single jar. I am trying to add a folder which contains all the jars in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
Project --> java build Path --> libraries --> add library --> user library --> new --> give a name and click ok to create user library --> click on add external jars to add all jars from Common libraries folder
```

This will add the jars to a common library which can be added to the parent project.